# how to Send Multiple files from Server to Client?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, sockets, client-server

I am creating a project which requires a server to send multiple text files to 4 clients through socket programming. I am connecting those 4  clients to a server through multithreading, but I am facing a PROBLEM in sending multiple text files to a client. Here is my code for sending and receiving multiple text files. The errors I am facing are mentioned in comments in my code

note: OutputBase is my directory to text file

Server:

```
for y in range(1,x,2):
    with open(outputBase+str(y)+'.txt','rb') as f:
    w=os.path.getsize(outputBase+str(y)+'.txt')
    l = f.read(w)
    filesize=str(w)+'\n'       #here is a error:a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
    c.send(filesize)
    c.send(l)
    f.close()`
```

Client:

```
with open('received_file'+str(j), 'wb') as f:
        print('file opened')
        buf=''
        sep="\n"
        while sep not in buf:
            buf+=c.recv(5)    #If Text filesize is of 2 bytes, then after receiving 2 bytes the client in merging those 2 bytes with the inside data of Text file
        filesize=int(buf)
        if not filesize:
                break 
        data=c.recv(filesize)
        f.write(data)
        f.close
    j+=1
```

Comment: (1) The error in the server is one line below the marked line. You have to `encode` the string to convert it to bytes. (2) Is there an error in the client (which is syntactically incorrect due to the dot, by the way)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher there is no error of dot, I put it by mistake while doing  copy and paste